# Qual é a classe de palavra de sujeitos em frases preposicionais?

Tags: pronomes, preposições, infinitivo-pessoal

Então no português nós falamos "antes de *eu* entrar," a minha pergunta trata de "qual é a classe de palavra de *eu* nesse contexto?"

O verbo mesmo é o objeto da preposição, e "antes de" é uma preposição (composta), mas eu não posso identificar qual função o pronome pessoal *eu* tem aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, *eu* é um **pronome** que está sendo empregado como o sujeito da frase.